# coffeescript and repetition of code. Is there a solution?

Tags: coffeescript

So - I am really really digging coffeescript. But, I am curious how the possibility of repetition of code is dealth with across a large repository of code.

For instance.

Lets say I create a simple class.

```
class Cart
    constructor: (@session, @group) ->


class Shoes extends Cart
```

compiler will create  __extends and __hasProp methods.

Mind you, this is just one example -- pretty much this happens with loops etc... So, granted each bit of code is usually in its walled garden.. BUT, there could be many many of the same methods thru-out a code base.... because of the compiler just creating generic helper methods that are all the same.

Anyone else have to contend with this or deal with that possible bloat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably a lot more specific to what build tool you are using to manage a large codebase. [grunt-contrib-coffee](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee#join) for example provides the ability to concatenate before compilation which means something like the `__extends` method should only get declared once. Likewise, I believe, asset pipeline in rails makes similar optimizations through the `require` statements.